# Thirdweb useContract function return undefined

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract

Hello guy's I'm using thirdweb for smart contracts complying, deploying, and interacting with smart contracts. but I have an issue with third web when I pass my contract address to useContract function then it's return an object inside of that object we have contract key, and use the that contract key to interact with smart contracts but useContract return undefined I don't know what's going wrong.

```js
const { contract } = useContract('0x522fcFd2324c470C494a88bEAD1a6C7296cCf7C4');
  console.log(contract)
```

Comment: is it async? await useContract(...)

Comment: But in the docs it's not async function